# Struts2 jQuery Conflict - jquery dataTables and the Struts2 Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, struts2, datepicker, datatables, struts2-jquery

I currently facing a problem of comptatibility working both with Datatables and the Struts2 Jquery Plugin.
The only initialization of the struts2 jquery plugin (ie. ) makes my datatables not working anymore.
when i remove  my datatable workfine , but i need to use Struts2 Jquery Plugin for display and working with datepicker

I'm using this in my jsp file  :

```
<%@taglib  uri="/struts-jquery-tags"        prefix="sx" %>
<head>  <sx:head  jquerytheme="flick" /> 
and this :
<script src="Ressource/lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="Ressource/lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.sorting.js"></script>
```

I need to use both in my project or if they are another way to submit datepicker

Answer (score 2):

i was solve this conflict by using this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<sx:head />
</head>
```

instead of

```
<%@taglib  uri="/struts-jquery-tags"    prefix="sx" %><
    <html>
    <head>
    <sx:head  jquerytheme="flick" />
    </head>
```

and use datapicker like  that :

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="name"  label="date" displayFormat="dd/mm/yy"                                                               value="today" />    
enter code here
```

solution 2

Now all work fine i'm using `struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.1.jar` with `jquery-min.js 1.7.2` , the$() syntax is always used by other scripting library, and causing the conflict issue and fail to call the jQuery function.Now i use this

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
   dt_b: function() {
        $j('#dt_b').dataTable({
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": '110%',
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "bScrollCollapse": true 
             ......
        });
    },
});
```

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  dt_b: function() {
        $j('#dt_b').dataTable({
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": '110%',
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "bScrollCollapse": true 
             ......
        });
    },
});
```

Thank you

Comment: S2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: This solves not the root cause. It just replace jquery with an really really old dojo version. I use in one project datatable together with the jquery plugin without any problems. Would be great if you can post a concrete error message from your browser console.

Comment: so can you help me to fixe that. what version  you using in your app?

Comment: You should mark your own answer as accepted - I am sure it will help other people in the future.